# Save "Viewed Pages" and "Current Page" in the LiveChatTranscript record

Tags: liveagent

My problem was described [here](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000DlczAAC). We need to save inforamtion about "Viewed Pages" and "Current Page" in the LiveChatTranscript record. Maybe somebody know any solution how to save this data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

During my investigation [Salesforce Console Integration Toolkit Developer Guide](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.206.0.api_console.meta/api_console/sforce_api_console_intro.htm) I discover that it possible to get list of all **Viewd Pages** by user through
the method [getDetailsByChatKey()](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.206.0.api_console.meta/api_console/sforce_api_console_getDetailsByChatKey.htm). **Viewd Pages** that we can see on UI in the LiveChatTranscipt record when status is "In progress" are stored in **breadcrumbs** array of **details** Object that return after we invoke this method.